# Excel formula using relative row and constant value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am using the following Excel formula to get the relative row number for a calculation.

```
=$A9*(C3)
```

Cell C3 contains a constant value, so I always want to use that value, regardless of the row.
When I apply the function to the rows, the rows increment correctly, but Excel is also incrementing the C column to C4, then C5, then C6. I want the formula to always use the value in C3, regardless of the row, how do I force it to do that?

Comment: Ok, figured this out on my own. To keep a cell reference constant in a formula, even after copying the formula around the spread sheet, simply use $C$3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `$C$3`. The dollar signs tell Excel not to vary that row/column.

Comment: Why does Excel vary the row with $A9, but not with $C$3? Just seems a bit non-intuitive, they should have used a different symbol to differentiate it

Comment: The dollar signs apply to rows and columns separately. `$A9` varies the row but not the column; `A$9` varies the column but not the row; `A9` varies both and `$A$9` varies neither.